# A code with 2 ifs keeps giving the first one's result

Tags: c

I'm kinda new to C and I've been tasked to make a program that counts the number of times ';' has been used in the file selected by the user. So I decided to make it with a bunch of ifs and it worked when I had the first one down (only one if) but when I added the else if segment it just spits out the first if's result (eof's number) and I'm out of clues as to why this is happening. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int s = 0;
    int ch;
    char in;
    printf("Choose which file to be opened: inpt , eof or cntr\n");
    scanf("%c", &in);

    if (in = 'eof')
    {
        fp = fopen("D:\\programming\\C projects\\kursova PIK 1\\kursova 1\\New folder\\eof.c", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file");
        }
        else
        {
            while (!feof(fp))
            {
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                if (ch == ';')
                {
                    ++s;
                }
                else if (ch == EOF)
                    break;
            }
            fclose(fp);
            printf("The number of times ';' was used is: %d", s);
        }   
    }
    else if (in = 'inpt')
    {
        fp = fopen("D:\\programming\\C projects\\kursova PIK 1\\kursova 1\\New folder\\inpt.c", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file");
        }
        else
        {
            while (!feof(fp))
            {
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                if (ch == ';')
                {
                    ++s;
                }
                else if (ch == EOF)
                    break;
            }
            fclose(fp);
            printf("The number of times ';' was used is: %d", s);
        }
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `in = 'eof'` and `fp == NULL` -- see the difference?

Comment: That's not objective-c, please edit your question so it's the right tag, and there's no need to mention the programming language in the title if the question is properly tagged.

Comment: also, it seems like you are not aware of what multi-character literals mean. [Just do a Google search for them.](http://google.com/search?q=multicharacter+literals+c)

Comment: @Juhana I've tried `in == 'eof'` and it still doesn't work

Comment: @igrilkul of course it doesn't – you're confusing characters with strings, as I've explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this much of the code:

```
char in;
printf("Choose which file to be opened: inpt , eof or cntr\n");
scanf("%c", &in);

if (in = 'eof')
```

You've set the code to read a single character, which is not itself a major problem.  You should probably use `" %c"` as the format to skip leading blanks, but that's a refinement.

You should check that `scanf()` succeeded:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &in) != 1)
    return 1;
```

You then try to compare your single character input with multiple characters.  And, as pointed out in the comments, this is unsuccessful because instead of comparing, you assign (the difference between `==` and `=`).  The multicharacter character literal is non-portable.  The one thing that is guaranteed, though, is that the multicharacter literal is not zero, so your `if` condition is a shorthand for:

```
if ((in = 'eof') != 0)
```

and since the multicharacter constant is not `'\0'`, the condition is true, so the first part of your code is always executed, regardless of what the user typed.

It looks like you really need string input and string comparison, which is done with `strcmp()` from `<string.h>`.

```
char in[10];
printf("Choose which file to be opened: inpt, eof or cntr\n");
if (scanf("%9s", in) != 1)
    return 1;

if (strcmp(in, "eof") == 0)
```

These are the major initial problems; I'm making no guarantee that there aren't others to be dealt with.

And, as a general rule of thumb, it is better to end `printf()` statements with a newline.  You have:

```
printf("The number of times ';' was used is: %d", s);
```

You should use:

```
printf("The number of times ';' was used is: %d\n", s);
```

You seem to have the majority of the code in the `if` and `else if` blocks the same.  That suggests you should be using a function, or using:

```
char *filename = 0;

if (strcmp(in, "eof") == 0)
    filename = "D:\\programming\\C projects\\kursova PIK 1\\kursova 1\\New folder\\eof.c";
else if (strcmp(in, "inpt") == 0)
    filename = "D:\\programming\\C projects\\kursova PIK 1\\kursova 1\\New folder\\inpt.c";
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Did not understand '%s'\n", in);
    return 1;
}
```

You can then have a single copy of the code to open, read, close, and report on the contents of the file specified in `filename`.  Avoid repetition whenever possible.  Either make it into a separate function that you call with different parameters, or eliminate the duplication in the same general way that I showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't input a 3-letter string into a single-char variable. If you plan the user to input `eof` or something like that, you need to declare an **array** of characters, say

```
char userinput[ 30];
```

then input the user choice with

```
scanf( "%s", userinput);
```

and compare it to **string**, not the multi-character literal:

```
if( strcmp( userinput, "eof") == 0)
    process a file
```

instead of

```
if(in == 'eof)
```

Last, please note you use a doubled equal sign `==` to compare values. A single `=` is an assignment, not a comparison in C.

Comment: Please show testing the result of `scanf()`; otherwise, you've nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. You are comparing a multi characters against a character which is not right so inorder to compare strings use `strcmp()` as shown below and make the same changes in else if part of your code also.

```
char in[5];

scanf("%s",&in);

if(strcmp(in,"eof") == 0)
{
}
else if(strcmp(in,"inpt") == 0)
{
}
```